# Empty pdf file when saving figure to file using matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am trying to save a figure to a `pdf` using matplot, Python 2.7, and Windows 7. I can save the figure as a `.png`, but when I try to save it as a `.pd`f, the file is blank. Here is some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

linewidthPlot = '2'
linestylePlot = '-'
markerPlot = 'o'
colorPlot = 'b'

xlabel = 'x'
ylabel = 'y'
title = 'x v y'

# Plot the data using matplot.
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.gca()
line1, = plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=linewidthPlot,
                  linestyle=linestylePlot, marker=markerPlot, color=colorPlot)

axisScale = 0.05
xmin = min(x) - (axisScale * (max(x) - min(x)))
xmax = max(x) + (axisScale * (max(x) - min(x)))
ymin = min(y) - (axisScale * (max(y) - min(y)))
ymax = max(y) + (axisScale * (max(y) - min(y)))
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.grid()

# Add a legend.
first_legend = plt.legend([line1], ["data"], loc=1, numpoints=1)

# Label the axes.
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.title(title)

#pp = PdfPages("discard1.pdf")
#plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
#pp.close()
plt.savefig('discard1.png')
plt.show()
```

This code works, but when I change the filename to `discard1.pdf`, or instead use the `PdfPages` function to generate a `multipage` PDF, I end up with a blank file. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the education of others:

As [Martin Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985733/martin-evans) pointed out, this is an issue with Adobe Reader and some other pdf readers being unable to view pdf figures created by matplotlib.

The solution was to change linewidthPlot = '2' to linewidthPlot = 2 in:

```
line1, = plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=linewidthPlot,
              linestyle=linestylePlot, marker=markerPlot, color=colorPlot)
```

Maybe this should be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following to the end of your script:

```
with PdfPages('discard1.pdf') as pdf:
    pdf.savefig(fig1)
```

This will then produce a PDF file of your figure.

Comment: This suggestion was unsuccessful. I also don't see how this is different from the commented code I mentioned above.

Comment: I tested it using Windows 7, Matplotlib 1.4.3, TkAgg, Python 2.7.9. It definitely produced your graph as a PDF.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Windows 7, Matplotlib 1.4.3, TkAgg, and Python 2.7.10. I also tried with the Qt4Agg backend in matplotlib.

Comment: That is strange, how big is your blank PDF that is created? Mine was 9,419 bytes.

Comment: That is the same size as my output file.... perhaps it could be the pdf viewer? I am using Adobe Reader XI.

If this is the case, I don't understand why Adobe shouldn't be able to render the figure.

Comment: Quite possibly, I was using the free Foxit Reader, and it loads fine.

Comment: It seems you are not alone [matplotlib generated PDF cannot be viewed in acrobat reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314255/matplotlib-generated-pdf-cannot-be-viewed-in-acrobat-reader)

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a pdf viewer issue now. Neither adobe or GSView can view anything besides a white sheet (using two different machines)...